# Error creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource[com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/storage/GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a project where i am calling Google Cloud Storage API from Firebase Cloud FireStore API. This is my Firebase code before adding the Google Cloud Storage dependencies.

**Main class**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**This is my REST Controller**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.controller;

import com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.entity.Review;
import com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.service.ReviewService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ReviewController {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewService reviewService;

    @PostMapping("/reviews")
    public String saveReview(@RequestBody Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.saveReview(review);
    }

    @GetMapping("/reviews/{name}")
    public Review getReview(@PathVariable String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.getReviewDetailsByname(name);
    }

    @GetMapping("/reviews")
    public List<Review> getAllReviews() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.getAllReviews();
    }


    @PutMapping("/reviews")
    public String updateReview(@RequestBody Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.updateReview(review);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/reviews/{name}")
    public String deleteReview(@PathVariable String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.deleteReview(name);
    }
}
```

**This is my Service class**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.service;

import com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.entity.Review;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteResult;
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Service
public class ReviewService {

    private static final String COLLECTION_NAME ="Reviews";

    public String saveReview(Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

       Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

       ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiFuture=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(review.getName()).set(review);

       return collectionApiFuture.get().getUpdateTime().toString();

    }

    public Review getReviewDetailsByname(String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        DocumentReference documentReference=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(name);

        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future=documentReference.get();

        DocumentSnapshot document=future.get();

        Review review=null;
        if(document.exists()) {
         review = document.toObject(Review.class);
       return  review;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Review> getAllReviews() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        Iterable<DocumentReference> documentReference=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).listDocuments();
        Iterator<DocumentReference> iterator=documentReference.iterator();

        List<Review> reviewList=new ArrayList<>();
        Review review=null;

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            DocumentReference documentReference1=iterator.next();
           ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future= documentReference1.get();
           DocumentSnapshot document=future.get();

            review=document.toObject(Review.class);
           reviewList.add(review);

        }
        return reviewList;
    }


    public String updateReview(Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiFuture=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(review.getName()).set(review);

        return collectionApiFuture.get().getUpdateTime().toString();

    }

    public String deleteReview(String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiFuture=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(name).delete();

        return "Document with Review ID "+name+" has been deleted successfully";

    }
}
```

**This is my Entity Class**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.entity;

public class Review {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**This is a class which reads the google service account key**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.firebase;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

@Service
public class FirebaseInitialization {


    @PostConstruct
    public void initialization(){

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("./serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-firebase-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-firebase-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Till here I was able to call my REST API and perform CRUD operations on my Firestore DB. Now i need to call the Google cloud storage API from my Firebase API. For this i added the Google Cloud Storage dependencies.

**My new pom.xml after adding the Google cloud storage dependencies.My new pom.xml after adding the Google cloud storage dependencies.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-firebase-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-firebase-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>2.0.4</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**My application.properties file**

```
gcs-resource-test-bucket=gcpfirebase

spring.cloud.gcp.project-id = lustrous-braid-326814
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:D:\\Downloads\\Eclipse\\keys\\serviceAccountKey.json
```

**Now after adding the dependencies and running the server i was getting the following errors.**

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)

2021-09-30 17:49:33.339  INFO 9044 --- [           main] .e.f.s.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication : Starting SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DELL-PC with PID 9044 (D:\Downloads\Eclipse\eclipse-workspace\springboot-firebase-movie-review\target\classes started by User in D:\Downloads\Eclipse\eclipse-workspace\springboot-firebase-movie-review)
2021-09-30 17:49:33.344  INFO 9044 --- [           main] .e.f.s.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-30 17:49:34.924 ERROR 9044 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : An incompatible version [1.1.17-dev] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]
2021-09-30 17:49:35.441  INFO 9044 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-30 17:49:35.460  INFO 9044 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-30 17:49:35.460  INFO 9044 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2021-09-30 17:49:35.657  INFO 9044 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-30 17:49:35.657  INFO 9044 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2156 ms
2021-09-30 17:49:36.380  INFO 9044 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for service account firebase-adminsdk-a6cts@lustrous-braid-326814.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2021-09-30 17:49:36.380  INFO 9044 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
2021-09-30 17:49:36.382  INFO 9044 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is lustrous-braid-326814
2021-09-30 17:49:37.827  WARN 9044 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/storage/GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2021-09-30 17:49:37.841  INFO 9044 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-09-30 17:49:37.864  INFO 9044 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-30 17:49:37.892 ERROR 9044 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/storage/GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.main(SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Builder.build(Storage.java:11194) ~[google-api-services-storage-v1-rev20210127-1.32.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.<init>(HttpStorageRpc.java:122) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:55) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:49) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:560) ~[google-cloud-core-1.95.4.jar:1.95.4]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.getStorageRpcV1(StorageOptions.java:121) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.<init>(StorageImpl.java:124) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:45) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:39) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.118.0.jar:1.118.0]
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:540) ~[google-cloud-core-1.95.4.jar:1.95.4]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.storage.GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.storage(GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.java:86) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are currently running with version 1.30.10 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.31.1 of google-api-client to run version 1.32.1 of the Cloud Storage JSON API library.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534) ~[guava-30.1.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:113) ~[google-http-client-1.39.2.jar:1.39.2]
    at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.<clinit>(Storage.java:44) ~[google-api-services-storage-v1-rev20210127-1.32.1.jar:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you actually read the error or only panicked? `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are currently running with version 1.30.10 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.31.1 of google-api-client to run version 1.32.1 of the Cloud Storage JSON API library.` this error message looks pretty clear to me. You need a newer GCP version.